# Javascript - Render dynamically generated XML in browser

Tags: javascript, xml, browser

I am creating an XML string using JQuery. I would like to open a new window to display this string to the user in order he saves it as an XML file.

I do not have a server side and I would like this Javascript script to be compatible with either Firefox and Internet Explorer browsers.

I found a lot of stuff but nothing works really well.

```js
uriContent="data:application/xml," + encodeURIComponent(xmlContent);
var newWindow=window.open(uriContent,'_blank','toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, copyhistory=1, menuBar=1, width=640,height=480, left=50, top=50');
```

or for IE:

```
var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = "false";
xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlContent);
var newWindow = window.open('','_blank','toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, copyhistory=1, menuBar=1, width=640, height=480, left=50, top=50', true);
 newWindow.document.writeln(xmlDoc.documentElement.xml);
 newWindow.document.close();
```

The first solution works almost fine for Firefox but not for IE:

[image: a data: url in FF]

The second source code opens a window with the XML content but IE does not recognize it as XML... So the user has to display the source code by himself. This is not very convenient.

[image: empty IE window]

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Should the user see the XML source (the tags) or a rendering (via CSS or XSLT) of the XML? If the first, why not simply putting it in a `<pre>` element?

Comment: Browsers are best at displaying HTML, not XML. That said, your second approach is the correct one.

Comment: The user should see XML tags. Indeed I didn't try with `<pre>` element.
Unfortunately, the second approach does not work.

Comment: @Boldewyn - Whoops! Didn't read your comment before posting my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you treat the XML as content?

```
var newWindow = window.open('','_blank','toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1, copyhistory=1, menuBar=1, width=640, height=480, left=50, top=50', true);
var preEl = newWindow.document.createElement("pre");
var codeEl = newWindow.document.createElement("code");
codeEl.appendChild(newWindow.document.createTextNode(xmlContent));
preEl.appendChild(codeEl);
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(preEl);
```

... then you can use something like [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) or [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to add whatever highlighting you need.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd do. +1